# I'm writing a function to compare to music artist strings, but come in different formats. Would would be a suggested approach?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function

**Overview:**

I'm writing a function to compare to music artist strings, but come in different formats. Would would be a suggested approach?

**Example Strings (Both are from the same song, just formatted differently):**

```
// Eli & Fur & Brothertiger
// Brothertiger, Eli & Fur
```

**Question:**

What would be the suggested approach to compare these strings that I could match both artists `"Eli & Fur & Brothertiger"` and `"Brothertiger, Eli & Fur"`?

**Possible Options:**

- Use `string.split(',')` on `songTitle`, then for loop over each string
- Use `string.split('&')` on `songTitle`, but then that gets messed with with an artist name `such as "Eli & Fur"` with a `"&"` in it.

Comment: First you must know all possible formats you want to support. Your example so far suggest that '&' and ',' are separator and the order of the rest is of no matter.

Comment: But do you also have to support "Lou Reed" and "Springsteen, Bruce"?  If so, things get complicated quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd split by *either* `&` or a comma.

```js
const toArr = str => str.split(/ *(?:&|,) */);
console.log(toArr('Eli & Fur & Brothertiger'));
console.log(toArr('Brothertiger, Eli & Fur'));
```

Then check that the lengths are the same and that every element of one array exists in the other.

Comment: i think he needs Eli & Fur as one artist?

Comment: If that's desirable, the data doesn't look structured to make such a distinction possible. `Eli & Fur & Brothertiger` - separating that into two parts, not one or three, would be ambiguous

Comment: Thank you for your help! That's an excellent solution! Yea, it's just for comparing purposes, so this works out